# GPPSignIn problems on iOS with share extension and keychain

Tags: ios8, google-plus, keychain, ios-extensions

I've written an iOS 8 app (in objective C) that uses google plus sign in. The main application and its share extension use the same keychain, so that signing in from the main application using the GPPSignInButton provides auth for the extension. The problem is I can only get this to work if the two targets are run in a very specific order.

This won't work:

1. Open the main application and sign in (successfully)
2. Open the share extension and attempt "trySilentAuthentication" - this fails because for the share extension there is no auth in the keychain.

However - this does work:

1. Open the share extension first - as expected there is no auth in the keychain
2. Open the main application and sign in (successfully)
3. Reopen the share extension - this time there is auth in the keychain and "trySilentAuthentication" succeeds.

So it seems like the share extension doesn't get to have access to the auth in the keychain unless it was opened before the main application signs in. I don't think this is a general issue with keychains because I am able to share other types of objects in the keychain between the app and the extensions regardless of the order in which they're opened.

I’ve done some experimentation using two separate normal apps (no extensions) and I’ve found the same problem occurs - applications can share google plus auth in a keychain, but only if both applications have already had a chance to access [GPPSignIn sharedInstance] - they don't even have had to have done anything with the shared instance, just accessed it. If you sign in to one application first and then try to join in with the existing keychain then you don't get to access the auth that's already there.

Has anyone come across this type of problem before, or know how I could debug the auth process to find out why the order is so important?